# Setting remember on ajax laravel login

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Rebuilding my system using laravel 5.4.
I do an ajax login that works, but i want to add the remember option to the auth.
the documentation says this about setting remember:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember)) {
    // The user is being remembered...
}
```

But since my logincontroller does not have any visible login function, i am struggling with how to override it with my current logincontroller. 
in my route i am just calling LoginController@login. and i have no override on the login function being called..

This is my logincontroller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/minside';
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }
    protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            error_log($this->guard()->user(),'0');
            return response()->json($this->guard()->user(), 200);
        }
        return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
            ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => Lang::get('auth.failed')
            ], 401);
        }
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
            ->withErrors([
                $this->username() => Lang::get('auth.failed'),
            ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the LoginController class provided by Laravel, it does this check:

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->has('remember')
    );
}
```

Simply include '`remember`' to your request, to remember the user login.

Comment: Thank you, but where in my logincontroller would that go? i dont know where im actually doing the auth at this point

Comment: i added a remember_me to my form which does what i want, but i was hoping for a bit more control over my logincontroller.

Comment: The LoginController uses the trait AuthenticatesUsers, which has the attemptLogin functionality. If you want to have more control, you can either override functions, create your own trait or just create your own controller ;)